# for the program result about RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I have 2 questions

The result will be displayed like below.

> 1 1 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1 1 1
>
> 1 2 3 5 8
>
> 1 2 3 5 8

1. Why are the first three results the same?
2. Why the fourth one can work using the Remote Implementation object.

Here is the code:

FibClient.java

```
package fib;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.io.*;

public class FibClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            int numFibNum;
            String registryURL = "rmi://localhost:1099/fib";
            FibInterface h1 = (FibInterface)Naming.lookup(registryURL);
            numFibNum = 5;
            Fib c = new Fib();
            //numFibNum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            for (int i=0; i<numFibNum; i++) {
                h1.getNextFibNum(c);
                System.out.print(h1.getNextFibNum(new Fib())+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            for (int i=0; i<numFibNum; i++) {
                System.out.print(h1.getNextFibNum(h1.getFib(0,1))+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            Fib f = new Fib();
            for (int i=0; i<numFibNum; i++) {
                System.out.print(h1.getNextFibNum(f)+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            FibImpl h2 = new FibImpl();
            for (int i=0; i<numFibNum; i++) {               
                System.out.print(h2.getNextFibNum(f)+" "); 
            }
            System.out.println();

            f = new Fib();
            for (int i=0; i<numFibNum; i++) {               
                f = h1.getNextFib(f);
                System.out.print(f.getF1()+" ");                

            }

            System.out.println();   
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

FibImpl.java

```
package fib;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FibImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FibInterface {
public FibImpl() throws RemoteException {
    super();
}
public Fib getFib(int f0, int f1) throws RemoteException {
    return new Fib(f0, f1);
}
public int getNextFibNum(Fib f) throws RemoteException {
    sleep(500);
    int nextFib = f.getF0() + f.getF1();
    f.setF0(f.getF1());
    f.setF1(nextFib);
    return nextFib;
}
public Fib getNextFib(Fib f) throws RemoteException {
    sleep(500);
    int nextFib = f.getF0() + f.getF1();
    f.setF0(f.getF1());
    f.setF1(nextFib);
    return f;
}
private void sleep(int time) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Fib.java

```
package fib;
import java.io.Serializable;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Fib implements Serializable {
private int f0;
private int f1;
public Fib() {
    this(0,1);
}
public Fib(int f0, int f1) {
    this.f0 = f0;
    this.f1 = f1;
}   
public int getF0() {
    return f0;
}
public void setF0(int f0) {
    this.f0 = f0;
}
public int getF1() {
    return f1;
}
public void setF1(int f1) {
    this.f1 = f1;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question: In the first to cases you are creating a new `Fib` object at every remote call, so you always start with 0 + 1. In the third case, even though on the client side you are maintaining the same object, changes do to it over RMI are not visible.

You cannot change the contents of an object through a RMI call, because the objects are different. When you call a RMI method the object is serialized and deserialized on the other side, so two copies of the object actually exist. Changing the copy on the server side will have no effect on the client side.

In the fourth case you are using a local object to compute the Fibonacci numbers, so obviously when the object passed to the method is changed, the new contents are visible in the calling code.